# xml: encoding "utf-16" declared but Decoder.CharsetReader is nil unmarshal successful

Tags: go

I'm trying to unmarshal an XML feed containing German characters (e.g. ß, ä, Ö, ü, etc) into a struct, which results in the error: `xml: encoding "utf-16" declared but Decoder.CharsetReader is nil unmarshal successful`

Basically this is what I'm doing (omitted error checking for the parts that work):

```
resp, _ := http.Get(url)
defer resp.Body.Close()
bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err = xml.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &target)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I've tried to convert xml to json using `github.com/basgys/goxml2json`, I've tried to convert to string and back to []byte before unmarshal, I've tried to use various decoders posted in other SO answers (since it say charset reader is nil), such as:

```
reader := bytes.NewReader(bodyBytes)
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)
decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReader
err = decoder.Decode(&target)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

No matter what I've tried it fails to unmarshal/decode the xml feed into the struct.. in some cases it ends up converting all the text to Chinese rather than German.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the xml data you are trying to unmarshal, as well as the type definition of the target value.

Comment: Please provide a **standalone** example of the problem.

Comment: @mkopriva I'm still testing but it looks like the answer you posted before solved the problem.. maybe can repost it again so I can accept it :)

Comment: @jack I've removed it because I haven't actually tested it and I assume it could fail for some form of utf16 strings, in which case you would need to implement a reader that converts utf16 to utf8. I'll undelete the answer and add a note for any other reader who may stumble upon the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `charset.NewReader` you're using in the second example is from https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset then the code shouldn't even compile since the [`CharsetReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.CharsetReader) field has a different signature from `NewReader`.

---

To fix the error you can provide an "identical" charset reader, that is, one that returns the input unchanged.

```
func identReader(encoding string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    return input, nil
}

// ...

decoder.CharsetReader = identReader
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BiU4T2qz1Z1

---

**NOTE**: the above solution works for the example characters from the question but it may very well fail for other utf16 strings. In such a case a custom charset reader that can convert utf16 to utf8 should be provided instead of the `identReader`.

Comment: This worked for me trying to parse an xml with ```encoding="ISO-8859-7"```. Cheers!